# "Er glücklich war, eingeladen gewesen zu sein." Is this correct?

Tags: meaning, passive

I'm currently acquainting myself with the topic of Passiv and have a question regarding the use of Perfekt with Zustandspassiv as part of an Infinitiv Nebensatz. I'm aware that one may write this with the Vorgangspassiv.

> Er glücklich war, entlassen worden zu sein

But is it possible to get the same structure using Zustandspassiv mit "sein"?

> Er glücklich war, eingeladen gewesen zu sein.

Comment: "Er glücklich war, entlassen worden zu sein" does not sound right. You need to put the war in front of glücklich: "Er war glücklich, entlassen worden zu sein".

Answer (score 1):

It's

> Er war glücklich ...

The answer to your question is a short but clear **yes**.

It's totally fine to use *Zustandspassiv* here. In my opinion it sounds even better than the version with *Vorgangspassiv*.

Answer (score 1):

The passive constructions are both correct, but you have another grammatical problem:

Your sentende is either only a part of a full sentence, or its wrong. Note, that the inflected verb must always be the second part in a main clause, but the last part in a subordinate clause. So, either:

- main clause with verb at position 2:

  > Er **war** glücklich, entlassen worden zu sein.
  > Er **war** glücklich, eingeladen gewesen zu sein.
- subordinate clause:

  > Er lächelte, weil *er glücklich **war,*** entlassen worden zu sein.
  > Er lächelte, weil *er glücklich **war,*** eingeladen gewesen zu sein.